# Unable to return the default value for the object attribute in perl

Tags: perl, oop

I have a module , when I am trying to get the default attribute set in initialization, is giving the following error when subroutine is being called `get_name`

```
     Use of uninitialized value
```

sample code

```
     package test;
     #....
     #....
     sub new {
         my ($class) =  @_;
         my $self    = {};
         bless $self,$class;
         $self->_initialize();
         return $self;
     }

     sub _initailalize {
        my($self) = @_;
        $self = {
                     _name => 'NA'
        };
     }

     sub get_name {
              return $_[0]->{_name};
     }
```

valuable inputs required.

Comment: `"my" variable $self masks earlier declaration in same scope` https://eval.in/102140

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are redefining $self in the local scope of `_initialize` and assigning a new hashref. That way you are not adding the `_name` key to the blessed object. After `_initialize` is done, your newly assigned `$self` (with a plain hashref) is gone. Thus in `get_name` it cannot access the key `_name`.

```
 sub _initailalize { # btw typo here
    my ($self) = @_;
    $self->{_name} = 'NA';
 }
```

If you do it like this, you will need to assign each member on an individual line.

---

As a suggestion, this built-in style of OO is very tedious. Try looking at [Moose](http://p3rl.org/Moose) or it's derivatives as they are pretty powerful.